# Python urllib3 too many redirects

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I learn Python now and I want to create simple tool to opening few sites. I have next code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib3, ssl, certifi
from urllib3 import Retry, Timeout

def openurl(url, method = "get"):
    retries = Retry(connect=500, read=2, redirect=500)
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(
        cert_reqs = 'CERT_REQUIRED',
        ca_certs = certifi.where(),
        retries = retries
    )
    con = urllib3.connection_from_url(url)
    r = con.request(method, '/trades');

openurl("http://www.steamgifts.com")
```

But on this site script returns `Caused by ResponseError('too many redirects',)`

I try to fix this by `Retry(connect=500, read=2, redirect=500)` but I don't see changes.

Comment: is it possible there's a circular redirection here?

Comment: @DomTomCat my browser working on this site. Maybe exists blockade for scripts, I'm newby and I don't know how to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web site is blocking some user agents. You can pretend to be a bona fide webbrowser and not a sneaky hacker by setting your own http headers for the request. I'm not familiar with urllib3, but with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) it's very straightforward.

```
>>> requests.get('http://www.steamgifts.com/trades')
<Response [403]>

>>> requests.get('http://www.steamgifts.com/trades', 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'internet explorer or something'})
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: I try to use this: `urllib3.util.request.make_headers(user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko")` but still not working

Comment: How about just using the requests module instead? It's much more user friendly.